# How to disable logs for MongoDB in minecraft Spigot plugin?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, minecraft, spigot

I'm trying to hide Level.INFO logs from MongoDB because it takes too much space in my console (it literally takes me about 50 lines in cmd).

That is code that i tried:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

and my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need this:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

These are the imports required:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Here's a one line code for doing this:

```
((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

It sets all logs to only error.

Comment: That also doesn't work for me

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it properly? My tests have worked.